# Split ets in erlang

Tags: erlang, ets

I've a work in a course with mapReduce algorithem so i  built an ets table in Erlang from a big data file and I would like to work on it concurrently.
The table turned out to be very big and I would like to know if there is a way to split the one big table into a few smaller tables so that I can search the table concurrently
using mapReduce algo, Is there any way to split one big table into sub tables???
Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

You can search an ETS table concurrently without any need to split the table already:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#new_2_read_concurrency

If the table is large, I would recommend you use a good match pattern to help reduce the search size: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#select-2

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on an intranet app in which i had to keep things in RAM most of the time. I created a stable `caching library` which helped me abstract the `ETS` mechanisms. In this library, i create to worker `gen_servers` whose work is to create, own and expose methods for `ETS` tables. I named them: `cache1` and `cache2`. These two keep transferring ownership to each other in a redundant fashion in case one of them gets a problem. Get application:  http://www.4shared.com/zip/z_VgKLpa/cache-10.html
  Just unzip it and use the `Emake file` to re-compile it, and then put it into your `Erlang Lib directory`
To see how it works, here is a shell intraction.

```
F:\programming work\cache-1.0>erl -pa ebin
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> application:start(cache).
ok
2> rd(student,{name,age,sex}).
student
3> cache_server:new(student,set,2).
ok
4> cache_server:write(#student{name = "Muzaaya Joshua",
                        sex = "Male",age = (2012 - 1987) }).
ok
5> cache_server:write(student,[#student{name = "Joe",sex = "Male"},
                #student{name = "Mike",sex = "Male"}]).
ok
6> cache_server:read({student,"Muzaaya Joshua"}).
[#student{name = "Muzaaya Joshua",age = 25,sex = "Male"}]
7> cache_server:read({student,"Joe"}).
[#student{name = "Joe",age = undefined,sex = "Male"}]
8> cache_server:get_tables().
[{cache1,[student]},{cache2,[]}]
9> rd(class,{class,no_of_students}).
class
10> cache_server:get_tables().
[{cache1,[student]},{cache2,[]}]
11> cache_server:new(class,set,2).
ok
12> cache_server:get_tables().
[{cache1,[student]},{cache2,[class]}]
13> cache_server:write(class,[
        #class{class = "Primary " ++ integer_to_list(N),
        no_of_students = random:uniform(50)} || N <- lists:seq(1,7)])
.
ok
14> cache_server:read({class,"Primary 6"}).
[#class{class = "Primary 6",no_of_students = 30}]
15> cache_server:delete({class,"Primary 2"}).
ok
16> cache_server:get_cache_state().
[{server_state,cache1,1,[student]},
 {server_state,cache2,1,[class]}]
17> rd(food,{name,type,value}).
food
18> cache_server:new(food,set,2).
ok
19> cache_server:write(food,[#food{name = "Orange",
                        type = "fruit",value = "Vitamin C"}]).
ok
20> cache_server:get_cache_state().
[{server_state,cache1,2,[food,student]},
 {server_state,cache2,1,[class]}]
21>
```

Now, to understand the importance of `ets:give_away/3`, lets see what happens when either `cache1` or `cache2` crashes. Remember that the current server state (which shows the current owner of a table) is:

```
21> cache_server:get_cache_state().
[{server_state,cache1,2,[food,student]},
 {server_state,cache2,1,[class]}]
22>
```

Let me crash `cache1` and we see.

```
22> gen_server:cast(cache1,stop).
ok
        Cache Server: cache2 has taken over table: food from server: cache1
23>
        Cache Server: cache2 has taken over table: student from server: cache1
23> cache_server:get_cache_state().
[{server_state,cache1,0,[]},
 {server_state,cache2,3,[student,food,class]}]
24>
```

And likewise the other one:

```
24> gen_server:cast(cache2,stop).
ok
        Cache Server: cache1 has taken over table: student from server: cache2
25>
        Cache Server: cache1 has taken over table: food from server: cache2
25>
        Cache Server: cache1 has taken over table: class from server: cache2
25> cache_server:get_cache_state().
[{server_state,cache1,3,[class,food,student]},
 {server_state,cache2,0,[]}]
26>
```

Thats it ! You could use the concepts in the source code to create something on your own. The `ETS` tables created by that library are `public` and `named` , so you can directly access them using `ETS` functions.